# Is there a way to install Pypy3 on Arago Project?

Tags: python, linux, embedded, pypy, texas-instruments

I am trying to install pypy3 in TI's ARM embedded system.

It was based on linux, so I thought I could install pypy3 like I can do in linux system, but it did not work that way.

Here is what I've done:

unzip the zip file to /opt

made symlink to /usr/local/bin by ln -s opt/pypy3/bin usr/local/bin

I have checked that contents of opt/pypy3/bin are in usr/local/bin.

In each directory, libpypy3-c.so, pypy3, libpypy3-c.so.debug, and pypy3.debug exists

Then when I try pypy main.py, it doesn't work.

It just says -sh: pypy: command not found

They are the ordinary steps of installing pypy in linux.

Is there anyone who has any idea to solve this problem?

**Added**

When I directly run pypy3 like `./../opt/pypy3/bin/pypy3 main.py`, an error message pops up says:

> ./../opt/pypy3/bin/pypy3: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libbz2.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Comment: You are going to need a version compiled for your ARM architecture.

Comment: @KlausD. What does it mean?

Comment: PyPy contains binaries with compiled code. They are compiled for a specific architecture and against specific libraries. Most PCs have the x86_64 architecture, while ARM is an architecture on its own. x86_64 binaries don't run on ARM. So, you have to make sure you installed the right version.

Comment: @KlausD. I've installed `ARM Softfloat Linux binary (ARMEL/gnueabi, Ubuntu Raring)` one.

Answer (score 0):

What processor does the TI use? The arm downloads are based on raspberry PI or equivalent. Try the hard float one from here http://www.pypy.org/download.html

Comment: Sitara™ AM437x with single core.

Comment: I've tried the same process with hard float one, but I get the same result. `-sh: pypy3: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you need to add the location of the pypy binary to your `$PATH`
2. Read again the sentence [here](https://www.pypy.org/download.html#linux-binaries-and-common-distributions) "Linux binaries are only usable on the distributions written next to them". You will need to figure out how to get those dependencies on your distribution, using your OS's package manager. If you work it out, please share your solution so others can reuse it.